# devops , how to create user using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, devops

am newbi to devops and got a task to create user , am using ansible in my control machine and want to create a new user with password in server2

playbook i have written is

```
hosts:appservers
user:test
sudo:yes
gather_facts:yes 
var :
    password:centos
task:
  - name: creating user
    user: name=john password={{password}}
```

after running the above script i tried to login with that user on another server as

```
[root]# su - test
```

after doing the above step it didnt asked for the password and took me to the test user as

```
[test@localhost ~]$
```

y it is not asking for the password ?

Answer (score 1):

Root doesn't need a password to switch users. Try using `ssh test@localhost` to test the password.